# How can I get the data from Firebase realtime as JSON without the key identifiers

Tags: android, json, firebase, search, firebase-realtime-database

[Image one[image two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfnvP.png)

I have two images, showing the output of a json. Image one shows data from firebase realtime database and the other is just regular json. I would like to retrieve data from firebase so that it appears without the key identifier UUID, just like the regular json. How can I go about that.
https://www.androidhive.info/2017/11/android-recyclerview-with-search-filter-functionality/
the above is a link to the app that I want to replicate but this time round using firebase as the source of the data.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do. Plus: it allows you to then also include an example of what you mean by "just regular JSON", as that is not clear at the moment.

Comment: Please add to your question what Frank van Puffelen asked for and responded with @.